# Schedule live streaming channels in Azure Media Services to start programatically at a certain time

Tags: .net, azure, azure-media-services

I have two live streaming channels on Microsoft Azure Media Services that I would like to start and stop programatically at a certain time each day. I've been looking through the Azure documentation but haven't found a clear way forward. What would be a standard workflow using the Azure tools/SDKs/APIs to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are APIs to start and stop Channels and Programs.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/media/operations/channel#a-namestartchannelsa-start-channels

I would recommend using a service like Azure Scheduler to trigger the events
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/scheduler/

Another option is to wrap the API in an Azure Function and call that from any other service that can do the timing or notification of the stop/start times.